# How to use PhotonPeer in Unreal Engine 4.8

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I'm trying to implement PhotonPeer in Unreal Engine 4.8 but I'm stuck at the connect function. I need to provide an AppId, but nothing I try is accepted by UE4.

Here's my code:

DALGameInstance.h

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "Engine/GameInstance.h"
#ifdef __clang__
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Woverloaded-virtual"
#endif
#if _EG_WINDOWS_PLATFORM
#include "AllowWindowsPlatformTypes.h"
#endif
#pragma warning (disable: 4263)
#pragma warning (disable: 4264)
#include "Photon/Photon-cpp/inc/PhotonPeer.h"
#include "Photon/Photon-cpp/inc/PhotonListener.h"
#pragma warning (default: 4263)
#pragma warning (default: 4264)
#if _EG_WINDOWS_PLATFORM
#include "HideWindowsPlatformTypes.h"
#endif
#include "DALGameInstance.generated.h"

/**
 * 
 */
UCLASS()
class DALGAME_API UDALGameInstance : public UGameInstance
{
    GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()

public:
    //UDALGameInstance(const class FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer);
    ExitGames::Photon::PhotonPeer* peer;
    ExitGames::Photon::PhotonListener* listener;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = DALGameInstancePhoton)
    FString ServerAddress = "127.0.0.1:5055";
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = DALGameInstancePhoton)
    FString ApplicationName = "MasterServer";
};
```

DALGameInstance.cpp

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#include "DALGame.h"
#include "DALGameInstance.h"

UDALGameInstance::UDALGameInstance(const class FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer) : Super(ObjectInitializer)
{
    peer = new ExitGames::Photon::PhotonPeer(*listener, ExitGames::Photon::ConnectionProtocol::UDP);
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Connecting to server"));
    if(!peer->connect(*ServerAddress, **ApplicationName**))
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Connection failed"));
    }
    else
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Connection established"));
    }
}
```

The **part** with ApplicationName is the problem. BuildTool complains No suitable conversion from FString to const nByte. I have tried everything to get this up and running but with no luck at all.

Does someone have the same issue or a hint at what I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution with help from Exitgames.

DALGameInstance.h

```
/* ToDo: Find a way to get nByte as UPROPERTY! */
//UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = DALGameInstancePhoton)
nByte* ApplicationName = reinterpret_cast<nByte*>("MMOServer");
```

DALGameInstance.cpp

```
if(!peer->connect(*ServerAddress, ApplicationName))
```

Try to implement listener now and view.